# Сбилась кодировка

Tags: python-3.x, vds, scp

При передачи Python файла на сервер сбилась русская кодировка. При запуске выдает данную ошибку:

```
await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, f'\u0417\u0430\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043b \u043d\u0430 {dateRecord}. \u0412\u044b\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f',
```

На хосте работает все отлично.
Пробовал вставлять

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vim:fileencoding=utf-8
```

Не помогло.

Comment: А где собственно ошибка? Это нормальные русские буквы, только в виде кодов символов. Если вывести эту строку на печать будет "Записал на {dateRecord}. Выберите время"

Comment: Так он ее как раз таки и не выводил

Comment: А, теперь понятно

Answer (score 2):

Оказалось все просто. Не был установлен русский язык в системе. Для установки необходимо выполнить:

```
apt install locales-all

sudo update-locale LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
```